# Cuando actualizo la contraseña de un usuario no puedo loguearme con esa contraseña, como modificar la contraseña en laravel?

Tags: laravel-7

Muy buenas!
Estoy intentando hacer un panel de administración de usuarios, y me encuentro actualmente con este problema, el código no me arroja ningún error, simplemente al parecer estoy cometiendo algún error al editar la contraseña de mis usuarios.
El hash se guarda en la bd, pero como dije, en el login me dice que las credenciales son incorrectas.

Este es mi código en el form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/usuario/'.$user->id) }}">
                        @csrf
                        {{ method_field('PATCH')}}
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre:</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">{{$user->name}}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Guardar') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

estas son las rutas

```
Route::get('user/{user}/editpass', 'UserController@editpass')->name('user.editarpass');
Route::patch('usuario/{id}', 'UserController@updatepass')->name('user.updatepass');
Route::put('usuario/{id}', 'UserController@updatepass')->name('user.updatepass');
```

y este es el codigo del controlador

```
    public function editpass($id)
    {
        $user= User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('usuario.editpass', compact('user'));
    }
    public function updatepass(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
        $user = user::findOrFail($id);
        $user->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->Password)
        ])->save();

        return redirect('/user');
    }
```

espero alguien pueda ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo resolvi de la siguiente forma:

```
        $user = user::findOrFail($id);
        $user->forceFill([
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'remember_token' => Str::random('60'),
        ])->save();
        return redirect('/user');
```

puesto que en el modelo User tengo esta funcion setPasswordAttribute que esta volviendo a encriptar el hash

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
```

se resolvió básicamente quitando 'password' => Hash::make($request->Password) y poniendo simplemente 'password' => $request->input('password')

Comment: No tuve en cuenta hablarte de los mutators y accesors. Son muy interesantes. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. :D

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme @cooper !!

Answer (score 0):

No se si estará aquí el origen del problema, pero uno de los problemas que presenta el código es que los atributos que vienen en el *request* son *case-sensitive*. Es decir, que no es lo mismo "password" que "Password".

Prueba a modificar la línea en la que haces el llenado:

```
    $user->fill([
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
    ])->save();
```

Otro asunto a tener en cuenta al utilizar el método *fill* es que en el modelo correspondiente debes tener definidos todos los campos en los que quieres permitir la asignación en masa. Es decir, en tu caso, en el modelo debes tener al menos el campo *password* asignado:

```
protected $fillable = [..., 'password', ...];
```

Comment: Cual es la ventaja de usar `$user->fill(['password' => Hash::make($request->password)])` en vez de `$user->password = Hash::make($request->password);`?? Pregunto por curiosidad, ya que hace poco que empecé a usar Laravel y siempre que edito lo hago asignando valores directamente

Comment: Que tal @cooper !! espero que estes bien.

Comment: pues mira, en parte creo sirvio, aunque seguia sin funcionar, lo que hice fue sacar del model User la funcion public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }

Comment: ahi si funciona cuando edito una contraseña, pero ya no funciona al crear un usuario. Esa funcion es la que me esta generando el inconveniente

Comment: voy a intentar mover esa funcion al register controller a ver si ya no interfiere al editar

Comment: @Benito-B, el método *fill* te permite hacer asignaciones en masa, es decir, de golpe. Si por ejemplo tienes un formulario con campos: name, password, email, phone_number y esos mismos campos están también en la base de datos (con el mismo nombre), el método fill te permite hacer la asignación de todos ellos de golpe y luego con un simple "save" los guardas. Echale un vistazo a la documentación de Laravel.